# does not contain a definition for 'Y' and no extension method 'Y' accepting a first argument of type 'X' could be found

Tags: asp.net

My newTransport.aspx button control

```
<asp:Button ID="najitRidiceButton" runat="server" Text="Vyhledat ridice" onclick="najitRidiceButton_Click" />
```

My newTransport.aspx.cs method

```
protected void najitRidiceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DAODriver.searchDrivers(Calendar1.SelectedDate, casPrepravyTextBox.Text, Int32.Parse(pocetOsobTextBox.Text), extraZavazadla());
}
```

Error i get

> CS1061: ASP.newtransport_aspx does not contain a definition for najitRidiceButton_Click  and no extension method najitRidiceButton_Click accepting a first argument of type ASP.newtransport_aspx could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

when i delete that button, everything works correctly, so i don´t understand it, this is my first ASP.NET web app so please help me i have no idea why it doesn´t work, although i tried to google it or find answer here on stackoverflow - no result

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/PageTemplate.Master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NewTransport.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="ASPDU1.NewTransport" %>
```

Comment: Is it possible you are refreshing the page without having Visual Studio rebuild the code-behind DLL?  Have you done and explicit right-click and Rebuild on the project?

Comment: Oh, i did so, and now, a new error appeared, saying it couldn´t load my master page, so it doesn´t even load the main page id loaded before :D

Comment: No errors or warnings reported when rebuilding?

Comment: YEEs it works, i had an error there so it didn´t finish rebuild before, after rebuilding succesfully it is working, thank you very much:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try by making the event handler `public void` instead of `protected`, just to see.  It works for me as `protected void`, but there maybe something here that I can't figure out from this sample.  I assume that the code-behind is pointed to the correct page in the ASPX markup's `@Page` reference.

Comment: I tried to change it to public too, but it didn´t help. The thing i donˇt understand is, that this method is generated automaticly when i double click the button in "split mode", so it should work, and even when i tried to drag a new button and make a new _click event it still doesnˇt work despite the fact all was done automatically without writing any code. Thats wierd.

Comment: Can you delete and readd the page too, see if that helps... maybe it's a bug with that page. I've had strange things like that happen.

Answer (score 1):

I have had great success with changing build configuration (e.g. from debug to release), run the project, and then change back to the previous build configuration.

Answer (score 1):

you seem to be using the ASP.NET WebApplication (i.e., not the ASP.NET WebSite) project type.
 If so, it is necessary to:

- Build the application and make sure that the build is successful;
- Re-deploy the required page/code/designer (or better a complete project) with the just built APPLICATION_NAME.DLL file onto the destination hosting server directory.